# Not able to change ssh port on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: ssh, openssh

I am trying to change ssh port from 22 to 1111. I have taken following steps, but not able to.

1. sudo nano /etc/ssh/ssh_config
2. Removed # where it says Port 22
3. Changed Port 22 to Port 1111
4. Ctrl + W -> Y -> Ctrl + O -> Enter -> Ctrl + X
5. sudo ufw allow 1111
6. sudo systemctl restart ssh
7. sudo systemctl status ssh

Output:

1. Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22
2. Server listening on :: port 22.

Comment: `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`  is the ssh *client* configuration file - for server settings, you need to modify `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Comment: @pa4080 thanks, I have added a brief answer below

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The file that you edited, `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` is the global ssh *client* configuration file - changing the port there will change the port which the `ssh` (and `scp`) programs try to connect *to*.

To change the port that the server listens *on*, you need to modify `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` :

```
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
```

Comment: please be careful to add a new port to the firewall